# How to increase default frame length acceptance of RSocket?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rsocket, rsocket-java, spring-rsocket

I'm using Angular JS as front end and RSocket (Spring Webflux) in the back end.

For sending large file from front end file upload action, I'm chunking file into multiple file parts and consuming it in the I/O stream at the back end. Now, I'm able to send 17 mb file and successfully store it at S3 file storage at the back end.

The problem here is the time comsumption.
The RSocket is accepting upto 63kb only, so it is taking longer time 15-25 seconds.
If I'm increasing file size beyond 63kb, it is throwing frame length error.
"unexpected error during frame handling"

RSocket Properties at application.yml file

```
`spring.rsocket.server.mapping-path=/rsocket
spring.rsocket.server.transport=websocket
server.port=7000`
```

I've tried adding the following properties as well,

```
`frame-length-limit
fragment-size
max-frame-size`
```

No luck, please guide.